# Configurar site no IIS no Windows 8

Tags: asp.net, iis, deploy, dns

Tenho o Windows 8 instalado em minha casa. Fiz um site em ASP.Net e  C# e agora fui colocá-lo no ar. Em minha casa, são dois computadores e em apenas um (desktop) eu configurei o IIS, o outro é para testar mesmo. Esses foram os passos:

> 1) Instalei o IIS em meu computador.
>   2) No painel esquerdo do IIS,
>   fui em site, direito e Configurar Novo Site.
>   3) Escolhi um nome para
>   o Site e um nome de host (www.agendamento.com.br)
>   4) Copiei os
>   arquivos publicados para uma pasta e escolhi essa pasta como a pasta
>   de trabalho do IIS.
>   5) Startei o site.
>   6) Abri o navegador (Chrome) e
>   digitei: www.agendamento.com.br.
>   7) O IP coloquei todos não
>   atribuídos e a posta deixei a padrão dele (80).

Quando digito o URL não vem nada.

O que mais devo fazer?

Comment: Você está querendo apenas publicar o seu site no iis, ou está querendo colocar um endereço de dns (www.agendamento.com.br) junto?

Comment: @Randrade até então não estava entendendo que eu precisava de um servidor DNS para poder acessar pelo nome do Host. Agora percebi que eu não posso fazer sem ele. Pelo IP também não consigo. Qual a finalidade disso? Eu preciso aprender, pois eu tenho um cliente que deseja que sua aplicação rode em seu ambiente de rede apenas, ou seja, todas as 6 máquinas deverão acessar o aplicativo e por isso estou testando em casa, em meu ambiente, para ao chegar lá, não ficar dando bandeira.

Comment: Seu site está em que? Web Forms? Asp.NET MVC? Asp Classico, ou alguma outra? Para eu elaborar uma resposta.

Comment: web forms. É sóum teste que eu estou fazendo aqui, para aprender a configurar o IIS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não pode usar um domínio qualquer. Você precisa usar um domínio que esteja configurado em um servidor de DNS. Você pode configurar um servidor de DNS próprio e configurar o domínio que deseja nele. Claro que só os computadores que estão "olhando" para este servidor de DNS conseguirão enxergar este domínio configurado nele.

Se você deseja que isto seja acessível pela internet, você deverá registrar este domínio em um órgão oficial para estar disponível em DNS público em toda a internet. OS domínios com final `.br` são registrados no [Registro.br](https://registro.br/). Mas este domínio especificamente está bloqueado para registro e só pode ser usado internamente (na verdade não aconselho usar um domínio que deveria ser público de forma privada.

Se você tiver um domínio registrado, pode apontar para sua rede se tiver um IP fixo. Ou pode usar um serviço que substitua o IP fixo como o [No-IP](http://www.noip.com/).

Mas acho que você só quer algo interno, então basta configurar um servidor de DNS para ter um domínio seu. Aconselho usar algo como `meusite.teste` ao invés de domínios válidos na internet.

Definitivamente eu faria isto em um Windows Server que tem um servidor DNS. Mas se quer insistir da maneira como está usando, instale o [MaraDNS](http://maradns.samiam.org/index.html). Isto tem a vantagem de poder acessar em outro computador desde que o cliente de DNS do outro computador esteja apontando para este servidor.

Outra possibilidade mambembe seria mudar o arquivo de *hosts*. Ele fica em:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Lá você adiciona (não vai apagar o que já existe):

```
127.0.0.1       meusite.teste
```

Ou se fizer questão:

```
127.0.0.1       www.agendamento.com.br
```

Claro que você também pode acessar pelo IP, ou mesmo `localhost`, se está na mesma máquina. Eu faria isto neste caso precário.

Se for acessar em outro computador, basta mudar o IP para este computador (vamos supor que o IIS está no computador de IP `192.168.0.103`):

```
192.168.0.103       meusite.teste
```

Claro que você também pode estar com problemas de *firewall*, se for isto, libere a porta do IIS na máquina onde ele está instalado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).